# Tableview - Creating numberOfSectionsInTableView based on data in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode4.2, tableview

I am currently creating a TableView application using sqlite and thus far, it works as intended.  The first view is a listing of all states in the United States and returns them in alphabetical order in one section called "States".  My question is...How do I create an alphabetical sectioned list for this data?  In other words, create a section named "A" that contains states Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas.  A section named "C" that would contain California, Colorado, Connecticut.  It would basically comb the results, looking for the first letter in each state and if there is a match, place that state in the appropriate section.

I have come across some articles that describes how to do this but not relative to sqlite.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to feed a structure that is an array of array. Each section of the array will contain an array of States that match the same first letter of states. Work on this structure then to implement the datasource and delegate methods.

As it happen to me to do something very similar, here is a code snippet to feed the structure (self.browserContents). I hope it will help:

```
BrowserContents *bc = [[BrowserContents alloc] init];

// Create an array to hold the sub arrays
NSInteger sectionCount = [bc getNumberOfCategories]; 
NSMutableArray *sectionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

// Iterate over each section, creating each sub array 
for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *singleSectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    [sectionsArray addObject:singleSectionArray]; 
}

// Fill up each section
 NSMutableArray *contentsTemp = bc.contents;
 for (BrowserStateItem *item in contentsTemp) {
        [(NSMutableArray *)[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:[item categoryId]] addObject:item];
 }

// Iterate over each section array to sort the items in the section 
UILocalizedIndexedCollation *indexedCollation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
for (NSMutableArray *singleSectionArray in sectionsArray) 
{
        NSArray *sortedSection = [indexedCollation sortedArrayFromArray:singleSectionArray collationStringSelector:@selector(name)];
        [self.browserContents addObject:sortedSection];
}
```

**Note:**
BrowserContents is a class that should contain the list of all states, the number of categories and id of the category it should belong to (e.g: A->1, B->2 etc... supposed you have states that start with A and B).  Last check the book **Professional iPhone and iPad Database Application Programming**. This has been a great ressource to understand database programming in iOS.

Comment: Tiguero - Thnak you very much for the reply and the sample code of me to reference.  Greatly appreciated!  I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

First, all of those non-sqlite examples are probably perfectly adequate. There's nothing special about getting the data from a NSArray or a sqlite database. Anyway,

A couple of options. First, this example is so trivial, that I'd probably just read in the state names (ordered, of course), and build my model as I went through (e.g. look at the first letter, if different first letter start a new section, etc.).

The second option is to read in the minimum data necessary to support the building of the model behind my tableview during viewDidLoad. The model I personally use is a NSMutableArray of Section objects, and each of those section objects consists of the section header and an array of Row objects, where those Row objects are just unique identifiers to the relevant row in the database. Then, to populate that model, I just do a sql statement like:

```
select substr(last_name,1,1), employee_id from employee order by last_name, first_name;
```

From that, I'd loop through and build the model of an array of sections, and for each section an array of unique identifiers for the individual items in that section.

Lots of other approaches, too. Hopefully this will get you going. If not, update your question with the sort of model behind your tableview, and perhaps some code of what you've tried, and we'd be happy to help you out more.

Comment: Robert, Thank you for the reply.  I appreciate your suggestions.  I will attempt the second option that you suggested.  Again, thank you!